# Fabric.js: what is the difference between `add()` and `addWithUpdate()`?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var a = new fabric.Rect({ width: 20, height: 20 });
var g = new fabric.Group([a]);
canvas.add(g);

var b = new fabric.Rect({ width: 20, height: 20, left: 30 });
g.add(b);
canvas.renderAll();
```

I expect this code to give me two squares horizontally separated by 30 pixels. Instead, it gives me this:

[image: squares not aligned!]

When I replace `g.add()` above with `g.addWithUpdate()`, I get the expected result. Why? I don't think I understand the docs; they say that `addWithUpdate()`

> Adds an object to a group; Then recalculates group's dimension, position.

I don't see what the group's dimensions or positions has to do with this. Can anyone shed some light? The real problem I'm having is more complicated than the one above, but I think is basically because I don't understand `addWithUpdate()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say is a bug, but is more a docs issue.
fabric.Group inherits from fabric.Collection and fabric.Object.
The .add method comes from the .Collection and is created more for the canvas and compatible with the .Group.

The point is that in the Group every object gets positioned relative to group center. top and left of every object get subtracted with the group center.

What `addWithUpdate` does is:

ungroup all objects
restore their original top and left
add the new object
regroup them all
--when regrouping:
--check bounding boxes of all objects,
--make a bounding box of the bounding boxes
--derive top,left,width and height of the group,
--subtract to every object top and left half the the height and the width.

What `add` does is:
put the object in the `_objects` array of the group

So as of now adding objects to group with just `.add` is really wrong.

Less wrong is:

create empty Group, add all objects with `.add()`, call an empty `.addWithUpdate()` and `.setCoords()` finally as shown in the fiddle.

You should consider this only if you are adding lot of objects without any user interaction between each other call of `.add()` method to save on some calculation.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var a = new fabric.Rect({ width: 20, height: 20});
var g = new fabric.Group();
canvas.add(g);

var b = new fabric.Rect({ width: 20, height: 20, left: 30, top:0 });
var c = new fabric.Rect({ width: 20, height: 20, left: 60, top:0 });
g.add(b);
g.add(c);
g.add(a);
g.addWithUpdate();
g.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="http://www.fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me a better way to do the code sample! Can you elucidate the difference between `add()` and `addWithUpdate()` a bit for me? For example, I don't understand why it would be necessary to recalculate a group's position when an object is added to it -- how does the object affect the group's position?

Comment: as soon as i check for the eventual bug i will add also the difference

Comment: added explanation. i do not know how this ended up in this situation, we did some recent changes in group management i do not know if this was broken even before.

Comment: thanks so much! How do I set the group's center? Is that just `g.top`, `g.left`, etc?

Comment: Group center is available at g.getCenterPoint(), and is derived from its top and left properties, plus scale, rotate and skew factors. if you want to set it  you have a couple of options, but explain better what you need  maybe in another question.